# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { ООП

Tags: javascript

```
/** Анимация. */
let lastTime = 0;
update(time = 0) {
  const deltaTime = time - lastTime;
  lastTime = time;

  figureController.updateGame(deltaTime);

  this._showTetris();
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

Ошибка на 3 строке (этот метод в конструкторе). Почему?

Comment: В конструкторе не может быть методов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструктор класса в Javascript может только вызывать методы и определить свойства при инициализации класса. Если вы хотите то можете вызвать в конструкторе данный метод. Например:

```
   class SomeClass{

       constructor(val){
         this.update(val);
       }

       update(...arguments){
         //Тут тело вашей функции
       }

   }
```

Comment: _но не реализовывать_ - через `this` вполне себе можно реализовывать: `this.update = function update(...arguments){...}`

Comment: согласен с вами